# Approximating the prime counting function

Tags: calculus, integration, prime-numbers, asymptotics

$\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. This function is very important in number theory.

$\Phi(x)=Ad \int_2^xc^{Ab}dx,$ where $A=1/\log(x),$ where $d,c,b$ are constants. Is there any combination of these constants that will give a best approximation or an asymptotic bound on $\pi(x)?$ I've tried many combinations. The most recent ones I used are: $c=5/4,$ and $d,b=1,$ but I'm curious what combination will approximate $\pi(x)$ best and how to find that combination. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your integral slightly. You've got $x$ in both the integrand and the limits (so it's simultaneously a free variable and not). Presumably you mean $\int_2^x c^{b/\ln(t)}\,\mathrm{dt}$.

Comment: Define *best approximation.* What are you objections against the standard approximations from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function.

Comment: Since $\Phi(x)=\frac{d}{\ln(x)}\int_2^x(c^b)^{1/\ln(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$, you can combine $c,b$ into a single variable, $c^b$. Comparing $\Phi(x)$ with $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, we can see that we want $d\int_2^x(c^b)^{1/\ln(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\sim x$. But I think the best you can get is $c^b,d=1$ since for any other variables, you have $\left(d\int_2^x(c^b)^{1/\ln(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)'\neq1$, which clearly means the two functions aren't asymptotic.

Comment: Note that $c=5/4$ isn't a good choice since $\Phi(x)$ grows faster than $x/\ln(x)$.